# Pourquoi est-ce que cette phrase n'utilise pas le subjonctif ?

Tags: temps-grammatical, subjonctif

J'ai trouvé cette phrase dans `News in Slow French`.

> "Il faut se tenir toujours prêt."

Pourquoi n'est-ce pas :

> "Il faut *que* se tienne toujours prêt."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Il faut que se tienne toujours prêt* n'est pas français.

***Il faut que*** doit désigner quelqu'un ou quelque chose.

Par contre, ***Il faut*** (sans que) nécessite un verbe à l'infinif.

> **Il faut que** tu fasses la vaisselle.
>   **Il faut** faire la vaisselle.
>
> **Il faut qu**'on arrête de gaspiller.
>   **Il faut** arrêter de gaspiller.

Ainsi, on peut dire  :

> Il faut qu'on se tienne toujours prêt.
>   Il faut se tenir toujours prêt.

Les deux formes sont similaires, et expriment la même idée.